# PHP - Сохранить значение переменной после обновления страницы

Tags: php

Мне нужно написать программу "угадай число" где есть некоторое количество попыток, если пользователь его не угадывает то попытки можно сбросить и начать заново. Столкнулся с проблемой что переменная отвечающая за попытки сбрасывается, global и static не помогают, страница обновляется и переменные переходят в исходное состояние. Как хранить переменные на php чтобы после обновления страницы от запроса переменные не сбрасывались?

Comment: в сессии, например

Comment: @splash58 Огромное спасибо, нашел как с помощью сессии хранить переменные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример. Перед началом Вашего кода:

```php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['tries']) {
    $tries = $_SESSION['tries'];
} else {
    $tries = 0;
}
```

Далее если пользователь не угадал число:

```php
$tries++;
$_SESSION['tries'] = $tries;
```

если угадал и надо очистить счётчик:

```php
$_SESSION['tries'] = 0;
// или
unset($_SESSION['tries']);
// или, если сессия больше нигде не используется
session_destroy();
```

Последний вариант лично я никогда не использую, но может
найдутся причины для этого.

В конце работы PHP-кода сессия сохраняется и закрывается автоматически.
Но, если надо это сделать вручную, например, чтобы выполнить какой-нибудь код после закрытия сессии, можно сделать так

```php
// закрыть и сохранить сессию
// или можно использовать session_write_close(), если версия PHP ниже 4.4
session_commit();

// тут ещё код
```

Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php).
Можно вместо сессий использовать [куки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php).
Но куки хранятся в браузере пользователя, потому лучше не хранить в них информацию, которую Вы не хотите показывать наружу.